# How to generate columns of intermediate width other than bootstrap's default column widths

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, multiple-columns

I started working on bootstrap recently. For my requirements, the bootstrap's default column widths aren't working great.I want to divide the width between col-xs-1 and col-xs-2 further into 12 more values, so that I can have something like col-xs-1.1, col-xs-1.2, col-xs-1.3 ..... col-xs-1.12.

I want to know the accurate way of doing it, because when I tried calculating these widths and specified them in media queries, the behavior in small screens is weird.

Please suggest me how to generate these classes which have all properties associated with the default col-*-* with required widths

Thank you

Comment: getbootstrap.com/customize, change `@grid-columns` to 24 (or whatever works for your needs, but from my understanding you want 12 additional columns), download and use new custom version.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this simply by using nested columns. So...inside each of your 2 columns you can essentially have 12 more split as needed. This is an example but you should get the idea:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        Nested
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        Nested
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        Nested
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        Nested
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        Nested
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        Nested
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```